# How can I create a mask by baking?

Tags: texture-baking

So I have a plane and an object, I want to create mask image: white where the object is and black where it isn't. How can I perform this? I'm searching for universal solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplest I have found is to assign separate material to them; one white emissive and one with black emissive, and then bake a texture with the Bake Type set to Emit.

[image]

You can also bake it from Diffuse if you already have black/white materials on them. You should then bake it from Color only.

[image]

Yet another way of doing this is to remove any backplanes, bake a Combined map (or any map BUT normal) and use the Alpha output of the baked texture as mask.

[image]

If you need to use the Compositing Editor to get the final image extracted from the image, you can use this setup:

1. Open the Compositing Editor
2. Add an Image node and select your baked texture
3. Add a View node
4. Connect the Image Alpha to the Color of the View node.
5. Open the Image Editor and select the View Node as texture
6. Save the image from the Image Editor.

[image]

Comment: What if I already have material(s) on the object? Duplicating the object each time I change something and reassigning materials doesn't sound good to me...

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Well, if I already have red material, for example, it will be baked as red, not white. That's the issue.

Comment: You are a bit hard to please ;-) But I have updated it again.

Comment: If I save image, it still uses Color and Alpha. I couldn't find how can I save it like this.

Comment: No, that needs to be done in the compositor or in an external program such as gimp or photoshop. Or you can choose to use it as it is and only use the Alpha output.

Comment: What is compositor?