# How to export textured mask as an image

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a simple node setup (picture 1) that is creating a mask on my 3d object (picture 2) and I want to be able to export this as an image to edit. **Is this a possibility?** When I go to the UV editor, the image isn't there for me to view/save.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133044/how-can-i-create-a-mask-by-baking